# Spring-Boost Application & Apache Ignite configuration: Problem while starting ApplicationContext

Tags: java, xml, spring, ignite

I'm trying to inject a IgniteConfiguration into a component like this:

```
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteException;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.*;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ImportResource("classpath:default-config.xml")
public class DefaultConfigurations implements IConfigurations {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
    @Autowired
    private IgniteConfiguration ignite_config;

    @Override
    public IgniteConfiguration getIgniteConfiguration() throws IgniteException {
        return ignite_config;
    }
}
```

The resource default-config.xml is holding a Apache Ignite configuration.

As long as i use following default-config.xml everything works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
(the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="workDirectory" value="E:\AVL\eclipse_workspace\dataservice\ignite_working_dir" />

    <!-- test configuration -->
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
            <!-- Set the cache name. -->
            <property name="name" value="testCache" />
            <!-- Set the cache mode. -->
            <property name="cacheMode" value="LOCAL" />
            <!-- Other cache parameters. -->
        </bean>
    </property>

    <!--
    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="default_data_region" />
                    <property name="initialSize" value="#{1L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}" />
                    <property name="maxSize" value="#{10L *1024 * 1024 * 1024}" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    -->
    
    </bean>
</beans>
```

But whenn i uncomment the dataStorageConfiguration property i get an error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext.

...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration#38875e7d' defined in class path resource [default-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1316) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.<clinit>(IgniteUtils.java:850) ~[ignite-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration.<clinit>(DataStorageConfiguration.java:86) ~[ignite-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:212) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.address field is unavailable.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2.run(GridUnsafe.java:1567) ~[ignite-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2.run(GridUnsafe.java:1554) ~[ignite-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe.bufferAddressOffset(GridUnsafe.java:1554) ~[ignite-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe.<clinit>(GridUnsafe.java:109) ~[ignite-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field long java.nio.Buffer.address accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.nio" to unnamed module @29b5cd00
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:171) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2.run(GridUnsafe.java:1559) ~[ignite-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
```

<strike>And the strangest behavior is:
When I run the application from Eclipse both configurations are working.
:-)</strike>

I'm using AdoptOpenJDK 16.
Here is the start script:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -f ..\pom.xml -Drun.arguments=--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED,--adDd-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-exports=java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-exports=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-exports=java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens=jdk.managemeDnt/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED,--illegal-access=permit
```

I have isolated the problem to JDK16.
Running the application with Java1.8 seems to work fine ...

Any ideas?

Edit:
After switching to AdoptOpenJDK-11 the problems seems to be gone.
Only a few warnings pop up:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2 (file:/C:/Users/POSCHR/.m2/repository/org/apache/ignite/ignite-core/2.10.0/ignite-core-2.10.0.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

@alamar Thank you!

Comment: What is the Java version here? Ignite supports Java 8 or Java 11 at this moment. See also: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start/java#running-ignite-with-java-11-or-later

Comment: @alamar Java version is AdoptOpenJDK 16

Comment: You may run into problems here, I recommend getting Java 11.